# I can't concatinate the strings using add function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = add("hello", "world");
```

This gives the output as: `hellohello` instead of `helloworld`.

Comment: add a little more explanation here for your problem

Comment: why using "add" in the first place? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Show us the definition of your `add` function, as that's where the mistake lies.

Comment: Add a little more explanation

Answer (score -1):

I'd use an array, which can have as many elements as you want.

If you have an array:

```
words = [ "hello", "world" ];
```

You can join it like this:

```
words.join("")
```

Your full code is then:

```js
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = [ "hello", "world" ].join("");
```

```html
<div id="sum"></div>
```